# Multiindex "get_level_values"-function for arbitrarily many levels

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, multi-index

Is there a way to construct a function that uses "get_level_values" an arbitrarily number of times and returns the sliced dataframe? An example can explain my need.

Multiindex:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo','foo','qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'four', 'one', 'two', 'eight','one', 'two'],
          ['green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'green','blue', 'black']  ]
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10), index=arrays)
s.index.names = ['p1','p2','p3']

s
                         0
p1  p2    p3              
bar one   green  -0.676472
    two   green  -0.030377
    three blue   -0.957517
baz one   blue    0.710764
    four  black   0.404377
foo one   black  -0.286358
    two   orange -1.620832
    eight green   0.316170
qux one   blue   -0.433310
    two   black   1.127754
```

Now, this is is the function I want to create:

```
def my_func(df,levels, values):
    # Code using get_level_values
    return ret

# Example use
my_func(s, ['p1'],['bar'])

p1  p2    p3              
bar one   green  -0.676472
    two   green  -0.030377
    three blue   -0.957517

my_func(s, ['p1','p2'],['bar','one'])

p1  p2    p3              
bar one   green  -0.676472
```

Above `my_func(['p1'],['bar'])` returns `s.loc[s.index.get_level_values('p1')=='bar']` and `my_func(['p1','p2'],['bar','one'])` returns `s.loc[(s.index.get_level_values('p1')=='bar') & (s.index.get_level_values('p2')=='one')]`

So, I want to put a list of arbitrarily many levels and a list of the same number of values and return the sliced dataframe.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it works for you : since ur multiindex has names, it is easier using [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax) for your function :

```
def my_func(df,levels, values):
    # Code using query
    m = dict(zip(levels,values))
    #create expression to use in the query method
    expr = " and ".join(f"{k}=={v!r}" for k,v in m.items())
    ret = df.query(expr)
    return ret


#function application
my_func(s, ['p1'],['bar'])

                    0
p1  p2  p3  
bar one green   -0.087366
    two green   1.126620
  three blue    0.868515


my_func(s, ['p1','p2'],['bar','one'])

                    0
p1  p2  p3  
bar one green   -0.087366
```

Comment: Thanks! The answer is very useful! The ```f``` and ```!r```  from this line ```expr = " and ".join(f"{k}=={v!r}" for k,v in m.items()) ``` are new to me. Can you provide some reference, where I can read up on those?

Comment: glad it works for ur use case. [format syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) should help with that. search for ```f-strngs``` and ```repr``` for more details on them.